# Internal Server Error while migrating to new server

Tags: craft3

I'm trying to migrate to a server from my local environment. I keep getting Internal Server Error. I have the latest version of 3+ of CraftCMS. Everything works fine locally but on the server not so much. Here is what I'm seeing in my Craft log file.

```
    2019-02-08 05:02:35 [-][-][-][error][yii\base\ErrorException:8] yii\base\ErrorException: unserialize(): Error at offset 352 of 93525 bytes in /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php:997
Stack trace:
#0 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/ErrorHandler.php(76): yii\base\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'unserialize(): ...', '/home/kinolicli...', 997)
#1 [internal function]: craft\web\ErrorHandler->handleError(8, 'unserialize(): ...', '/home/kinolicli...', 997, Array)
#2 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(997): unserialize('a:17:{s:12:"dat...', Array)
#3 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(982): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getStoredConfig()
#4 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(912): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getLoadedConfig()
#5 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(227): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getConfigurationFromYaml()
#6 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\services\ProjectConfig->init()
#7 [internal function]: yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
```

The PHP log file gives a bit more information.

```
[08-Feb-2019 13:36:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  unserialize(): Error at offset 352 of 93525 bytes in /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php on line 997
[08-Feb-2019 13:36:48 UTC] An Error occurred while handling another error:
TypeError: Return value of craft\services\ProjectConfig::_getStoredConfig() must be of the type array, boolean returned in /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php:997
Stack trace:
#0 /home/kinoliclients/public_html/jbbls/cms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(982): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getStoredConfig()
```

Also, just for context. I had the site running on the remote server but then did an update (the one that said, this is a difficult update). The update put it in a vegetative state (internal server error). The same update worked locally, so I then copied the files and database to the remote server hoping that would fix the issue remotely. However, it didn't. Was their a new PHP extension requirement or something, that might have done this?

Comment: Fly by guess: have you checked if a YAML file was created for projects and if this exists in both places?

Comment: No, their is no YAML file. Does PHP read that for something? I don't have that file locally where everything works, so I can't imagine that's the issue.

Comment: Try clearing out the Craft `storage/runtime/cache` folder.

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being an unserialization issue. After exporting the sql file, I updated it with the new domain. The serialization part within the craft_info table needs to have the correct character length in front of the domain. Fixing that fixed my problem.